# Preview .html file from remote AWS EC2 instance on local machine's browser

Tags: server, ssh, google-chrome, amazon-ec2

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508410/after-install-google-chrome-in-ec2-wont-open-from-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts-hvm) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425371/how-to-run-gui-applications-remotely-on-a-headless-server) I've gathered that I should ssh into my ec2 instance from my Mac by:

```
ssh -C -c blowfish -X -i user.pem user@hostname.com
```

This accomplishes X11 forwarding.

Afterwards, how do I preview an /path/to/index.html file in chrome or any web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For viewing plain HTML files on the local browser, you can use SFTP. Open the file browser (Nautilus) and go to *File* -> *Connect to a server*. The address will look like: `sftp://user@hostname.com`. You'll have to add your identity to the SSH agent (`ssh-add user.pem`) for key-based login to work correctly. Once connected, navigate to your HTML file and open them.

---

With X11 Forwarding, you can do this:

```
ssh -C -c blowfish -X -i user.pem user@hostname.com
# On the remote shell
firefox /path/to/index.html &
```

Firefox will open on your local system, but will actually run on the server.

---

A third option, if you're willing to set up a [static web server](https://askubuntu.com/q/520602/158442), is to set up port forwarding and then open it in your local browser:

```
ssh -C -c blowfish -X -i user.pem -L 9000:localhost:9000 user@hostname.com 'cd /path/to/; python3 -m http.server 9000'
```

Then, in your local browser, open `http://localhost:9000`.

Comment: Thank you for starting with the basics! However, I need to clarify -- there's no file browser. The files are on a remote instance that I interact with through command line. To open files from that remote machine in a texteditor on my local machine, I set up a reverse SSH tunnel. Is there a way to do the same except with a web browser?

Comment: @hiyume  Everything I'm talking about is done locally - in your laptop/desktop. Does it not have Ubuntu?

Comment: okay, whoops, I think I asked this question wrongly. the local machine doesn't have ubuntu, only mac, which means the question probably doesn't belong here. Interesting, everything must be done locally.

Comment: @hiyume then you can try at [apple.se].

Comment: I will figure out how to configure ssh on my local machine so this will work. After forwarding X11, though, do you just open the html file and it opens a web browser page? (if so, nice!)

Comment: you're wonderful, that was very clear :)

Comment: @hiyume one more option added.