# Access Ubuntu GUI through Putty

Tags: 14.04, updates, putty

I have a Putty connection from my Windows machine to my Ubuntu machine.
Everything works so far, I was wondering,if I can show the GUI of the Ubuntu machine inside putty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run GUI applications remotely on a headless server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425371/how-to-run-gui-applications-remotely-on-a-headless-server)